# Does PS have editable styles like InDesign?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

Does photoshop have a way to edit a style in the styles menu, and re-apply it across the whole document? InDesign handles this nicely, and saves a lot of time with indecisive clients.

Basically I would like to be able to mockup a website, and define H1 , H2 etc.. styles, and then go back, change the attributes (such as typeface, size) and then have photoshop apply those across the board.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: After spending 4 years working with InDesign in print publishing, the typography in Photoshop seems like it's decades behind InDesign!

Comment: The typography in Photoshop IS decades behind InDesign. To be fair, though, Photoshop was never conceived as a typographic layout application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

When I know I'll have to do this type of task in PS, I group type layers by their "styles" if it's convenient. Later on I can pop open the group, and Shift-select all the type layers in a "Heading" group for instance.

Then when I switch to the Type tool and make changes it applies to all the layers in the Group.

I haven't needed more than this simple workaround so far, but if you don't mind naming your layers carefully, essentially prefixing each with it's respective HTML tag, I'm certain you could come close to InDesign's functionality through a Photoshop action or a more complex script.

Comment: This is a good workaround, and something along these lines is as close as it gets in the current version of Photoshop.

Comment: Great work around! Now if only Adobe would listen :)

Comment: @SkinnyGeek: I don't think Adoe would implement this in PS, primarily as it's a _Photograph editing suite_. Lots of people use it for website mockeups definitely, but if it were to be implemented I'd expect it to be in Fireworks.